# Freeze a form while process is running using C#

Tags: c#, forms, process, freeze

I hope that you could help me with this problem.

I am launching a process through a form using a button, and then it waits until the process closes so it resumes the form. The problem is that the form is still clickable when the process is running, but it won't do anything until the process is closed. For example, if the process is running and I click on the button again, then I close the process, it is going to be started again as I pressed the button while it was running.

So, I don't want the form to be clickable at all.

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var something = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "something.exe"
        }
    };

    if (File.Exists("something.exe"))
    {
        something.Start();
        something.WaitForExit();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message.", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I also tried with:

```
            this.Enabled = false;
            something.Start();
            something.WaitForExit();
            this.Enabled = true;
```

But for whatever reason, the form is minimized when the process is closed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use a worker thread at all? If you do not want the GUI freed up?

Comment: Do you want it to freeze or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your code implies the main application is blocked when you call WaitForExit()...this just causes WM messages to be queue for your application and they will get processed once your message pump gets CPU again. One way to solve this problem would be to use a BackgroundWorker thread and not block your main application while it runs the process for you. Just before you start the worker thread, disable the main form, and in the worker completed method re-enable the main form. Make sure when you launch the worker thread you account for the process never returning...one way to accomplish this would be to start a timer before you launch the worker thread with a reasonable amount of time and if that timer expires before the thread completes cancel it and re-enable the UI.

Here is the documentation with the backgroundworker thread that is similar to what you are trying to acheive:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The form is minimized because your process is opening a console to execute. So what you need to do is execute the process without the console. See the `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var something = new Process {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = "something.exe",
            CreateNoWindow=true,
            UseShellExecute=false
        }
    };

    if (File.Exists("something.exe")) {
        this.Enabled = false;
        something.Start();
        something.WaitForExit();
        this.Enabled = true;
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Message.", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The form is disabled and enabled as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Thread then maybe just disable the controls not the form something like:

```
        this.SetControlEnables(false);
        something.Start();
        something.WaitForExit();
        this.SetControlEnables(true);
```

Where SetControlEnables would hold all the controls on the form Enable or Disable as needed.